# Print Logo & data in Gridview in Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form which contains a logo of the company and a gridview which lists a set of records (eg: 200 records) and below that is a set of text boxes and labels.

Is there any way to Print everything, i.e. the logo with gridview records and textbox and label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. To set you off in the right direction you first need to drop a PrintDocument on your form and hook up its BeginPrint and PrintPage events. To get it working you probably want to print preview rather than print, so you will also need a PrintPreviewDialog whose Document property points to the PrintDocument. Then you can call the following to see the print preview:

```
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

I have dug the code below out of an existing application.

In the BeginPrint handler you need to work out the total width of the grid so you can scale it accordingly when you print, something along the lines of :

```
    totalWidth = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
      totalWidth += col.Width;
```

In the PrintPage handler first you need to print the column headings, along the lines of the code below. You may want to include this code in the main loop (below) to print column headings on every page.

```
      foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
      {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(col.HeaderText,
            col.InheritedStyle.Font,
            new SolidBrush(col.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
            new RectangleF(l, t, w, h),
            format);
      }
```

Then you can print each row:

```
    while (row <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
      DataGridViewRow gridRow = dataGridView1.Rows[row];
      {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in gridRow.Cells)
        {
          if (cell.Value != null)
          {
            if (cell is DataGridViewTextBoxCell)
              e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(),
                  cell.InheritedStyle.Font,
                  new SolidBrush(cell.InheritedStyle.ForeColor),
                  new RectangleF(l, t, w, h),
                  format);
            else if (cell is DataGridViewImageCell)
              e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)cell.Value,
                  new RectangleF(l, t, w, h));
          }
        }
      }
      row++;
    }
```

A few things to note:

- The event handler gets called for each page. You need to decide when the page ends, and return with `e.HasMorePages = true` if appropriate. The variable 'row' is used to know what row to start from on the next page.
  You may want to print cell borders
- You need to keep track of the rectangle in which to print (above I have just referred to 'l, t, w, h'), so that the left is adjusted for each column printed and the top is adjusted for each row printed. Also, this is where you multiple the cell width by `e.MarginBounds.Width / totalWidth` to scale each cell.
- I have not done anything above to keep the aspect ratio of the images.

Hope this helps.